# in-place realloc with gcc/linux

Tags: memory-management, realloc

Is there such a thing?  I mean some function that would reallocate memory without moving it if possible or do nothing if not possible. In Visual C there is _expand which does what I want. Does anybody know about equivalents for other platforms, gcc/linux in particular? I'm mostly interested in shrinking memory in-place when possible (and standard realloc may move memory even when its size decreases, in case somebody asks).

I know there is no standard way to do this, and I'm explicitly asking for implementation-dependent dirty hackish tricks. List anything you know that works somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using `mmap` and `munmap` to eliminate the excess you don't need (or `mremap`, which could do the same but is non-standard), there is no way to reduce the size of an allocated block of memory. And `mmap` has page granularity (normally 4k) so unless you're dealing with very large objects, using it would be worse than just leaving the over-sized objects and not shrinking them at all.

With that said, shrinking memory in-place is probably not a good idea, since the freed memory will be badly fragmented. A good `realloc` implementation will want to move blocks when significantly shrinking them as an opportunity to defragment memory.

I would guess your situation is that you have an allocated block of memory with lots of other structures holding pointers into it, and you don't want to invalidate those pointers. If this is the case, here is a possible general solution:

1. Break your resizable object up into two allocations, a "head" object of fixed size which points to the second variable-sized object.
2. For other objects which need to point into the variable-size object, store a *pointer* to the *head object* and an integer *offset* (`size_t` or `ptrdiff_t`) into the variable-size object.

Now, even if the variable-size object moves to a new address, none of the references to it are invalidated.

If you're using these objects from multiple threads, you should put a read-write lock in the head object, read-locking it whenever you need to access the variable-sized object, and write-locking it whenever resizing the variable-sized object.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked on [another forum](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t444841-realloc-but-not-copy.html).  One of the more reasonable answers I saw involved using `mmap` for the initial allocation (using the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag) and calling `mremap` *without* the `MREMAP_MAYMOVE` flag.  A limitation of this approach, though, is that the allocation sizes must be exact multiples to the system's page size.